# I'm having errors "Workspace is closed" opening my Eclipse for the first time

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

When I opened Eclipse, it says that "workspace is closed", and doesn't open, every single time. It has problems intializing external folders, and workspace is closed. I posted pictures to see what appears on screen

["Sending build events with disabled autobuild" message "Has encountered a problem, workspace is closed" "Problems occured while trying to save the state of the workbench"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7lBY.png)

["Multiple problems have occured" "Workspace is closed" "Initialize external folders" "Sending build events with disabled autobuild"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISRkz.png)

[select directory as workspace c:/users/users/eclipse workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKivR.png)

I installed Java jdk 17 just a while ago and I don't know how this works. I'd try to look for it and need it to submit my coursework but I need help from making the package to the src folder? I installed Java including to instructions on the internet such as choose my directory in variable settings, and for Eclipse I just installed the latest version and ran.

Comment: How was this installed? What was installed?

Comment: does the actual user (the one running Eclipse) have full access on given folder (including the `.metadata` subfolder) ? What happens if creating a new Workspace?

Comment: @nitind I installed it from the official eclipse website with the latest version

Comment: @user85421 i didnt get to create a new workspace yet because it didtn open except for just one random time. i think i have full access, it's my laptop

Comment: you think?! Well, *I think* Eclipse should open the workspace without problems... it should not have been to hard or time intensive to test both points. I also think that maybe something is wrong with the file system - eclipse cannot read or write on part of the workspace (lock file, settings, ...) or there is some corrupted data in the `.metadata` subfolder, which contains workspace specific settings. Anyway, I never had that error (long time using Eclipse) and I cannot test or reproduce it myself, so I had to ask for you to do it  :-/

Comment: I would also suggest checking the log files... (I think it is `.../eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/log`) Also please consider the questions of the very first comment: "How was this installed? What was installed?" (There are MANY packages/versions on the *official website*)

Comment: @user85421 thank you i will. i installed https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-09/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers the latest 2023-9 version and for Windows x86_64